# linux removing temporary files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I was trying to remove files ending with a tilde using the command `rm *.*~`,but that does not remove files that start with a `.` and end with `~`, e.g. `.somefile~`. I've also tried `rm *~`, but that also does not work for files starting with a `.`. Can someone explain why that is?

I want to remove all files ending with `~`, regardless of whether they start with a `.` or not (I was trying to do that without find/exec). Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Files starting with a `.` are hidden by default, and don't show up in a normal `ls`. Because you may not have seen them, shells generally won't match these files unless you manually include them. You can do this as follows:

```
rm *~ .*~
```

Answer (score 1):

Though the above answer is probably safer (because of fewer side effects), for completeness....

The bash shell (which is what most people run on Linux) has a flag to say whether or not to include dotfiles in globs. You set it with `shopt -s dotglob`. The sequence below is before setting the flag, then after setting. Notice the rm will remove it once dotglob is set.

```
$ touch .somefile~
$ rm *~
rm: cannot remove `*~': No such file or directory
$ ls -A
.somefile~
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ rm *~
$ ls -A
$
```

A little bit less safe; in theory you may forget whether or not this is set. But if you want to set this everywhere, and you're consistent about it, it may be what you want.